# Using methods from visual controls in a console application

Tags: c#, console-application, richtextbox

I am creating a console version of an existing Windows form application. The WinForm application relies on methods from visual controls to do certain tasks.

For instance, there are calls to the RichTextBox control for some RTF formatting operations.

Is it possible to use methods of RichTextBox control from a console application without displaying a form? How?

Comment: yes, ofcourse. all controls in wpf and windows form are just regular classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly valid. You just need to add reference to "System.Windows.Forms" and you can create your controls within your code.

Eg.

```
RichTextBox r=new RichTextBox();

r.Text="Test";
```